# Why adding FOREIGN KEY constraint does not lock the table

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, locking

A "large" table :

```
mysql> select count(*) from MyTable;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  6594951 |
+----------+
```

Adding a FOREIGN KEY disallow to insert into the table

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT FK_DC7F6DF281F7EA87 FOREIGN KEY (key_id) REFERENCES Key (id);
```

Take almost 20 minutes during it is impossible to add a new row.

My question: but why mysql does not consider the table as a locked table?

```
mysql> SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE `Table` LIKE '%MyTable%' AND `Database` LIKE 'db';
+----------+-----------------------+--------+-------------+
| Database | Table                 | In_use | Name_locked |
+----------+-----------------------+--------+-------------+
| db       | MyTable               |      0 |           0 |
+----------+-----------------------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Thank you

Comment: A really solid question.

Comment: adding a constraint is pretty quick, the large part of those 20mins was ensuring all the existing data met the constraint.

Answer (score 2):

A guess:

Even though the table is effectively locked, `SHOW OPEN TABLES` is oblivious to it.

`LOCK TABLES` is a very old DDL statement in MySQL.  It was probably a kludge to let users manually simulate transactions.  At about the same time (version 3?) `SHOW OPEN TABLES` was added.

Once InnoDB was added, it became clear that `LOCK TABLES` was no longer needed; InnoDB does row-level locking for DML and transactions.

There are a few DDL statements that effectively "lock" a table even in InnoDB, but they probably come through a different part of the code.  That is (remember, I am guessing), `LOCK TABLES` and `SHOW OPEN TABLE` know about each other, but `ALTER` runs in a different circle.

Feel free to complain at bugs.mysql.com .

I checked 122 systems; according to `Com_show_open_tables`, only 11 used `SHOW OPEN TABLES` since startup.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is crap, and there is an open issue on it: I added a comment on [MDEV-15877](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-15877) linking to this post.

- [MDEV-15877 Expand open tables documentation](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-15877)

I believe there are **two types of locks** in play here.

- [Metadata lock (Strong MDL).](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/metadata-locking/) This stops table-modifications, but **NOT writes and reads**. I believe this is what we're referring to as a *TABLE LOCK*.
- Row-level locks. This stops modification of rows. This is being used by as the rows are being checked and held untill the DDL statement is complete.

In addition there is *"TABLE LOCK"* that you can get with [`LOCK TABLE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/lock-tables-and-unlock-tables/). The command `SHOW OPEN TABLES` presumably only reports this type of lock, which includes a MDL lock, because only this type of lock prevents reads and writes on the entire table.

This functionality predates MDL locking, and the docs indicate that it has since been modified,

> With the implementation of the metadata locking improvements in MariaDB 5.5, `LOCK TABLE... WRITE` acquires a strong MDL lock, and concurrent connections will wait on this MDL lock, so any subsequent `LOCK TABLE... WRITE` will not increment `In_use`.